# android /sys/class/net

Tags: android, networking

I found this post [Measure data roaming traffic on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394511/measure-data-roaming-traffic-on-android) there it say I shall monitor file /sys/class/net. I tried to find this on my emulator to see how it looks like. I cannot find it using the file explorer. Is that old out-dated information or where can I find it?

Thanks, A.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as for Gingerbread (and Linux kernel 2.6.35) `/sys/class/net` is not a regular file, it's a directory with a bunch of links to directories to real devices' statistics. It's perfectly readable with any permissions. Use Android terminal emulator (AppMenu -> DevTools -> Terminal Emulator) to see how it looks like. 
What it looks like. All files below `/sys` belong to a special kernel subsystem, they're not real files, just interfaces for reading information from kernel. Monitoring means just reading dedicated files that contains counts of transmitted/received/dropped bytes/packets/etc. 
E.g.
In the terminal emulator:

```
# ls -l /sys/class/net
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2012-03-15 16:49 lo -> ../../devices/virtual/net/lo
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2012-03-15 16:49 eth0 -> ../../devices/platform/smc91x.0/net/eth0
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2012-03-15 16:49 tunl0 -> ../../devices/virtual/net/tunl0
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2012-03-15 16:49 gre0 -> ../../devices/virtual/net/gre0
# ls -l /sys/devices/platform/smc91x.0/net/eth0
   ### ... A lot of files
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2012-03-15 16:47 statistics
   ### ...
# ls -l /sys/devices/platform/smc91x.0/net/eth0/statistics
-r--r--r-- root     root         4096 2012-03-15 17:03 rx_packets
-r--r--r-- root     root         4096 2012-03-15 17:03 tx_packets
-r--r--r-- root     root         4096 2012-03-15 17:03 rx_bytes
-r--r--r-- root     root         4096 2012-03-15 17:03 tx_bytes
-r--r--r-- root     root         4096 2012-03-15 17:03 rx_errors
-r--r--r-- root     root         4096 2012-03-15 17:03 tx_errors
-r--r--r-- root     root         4096 2012-03-15 17:03 rx_dropped
-r--r--r-- root     root         4096 2012-03-15 17:03 tx_dropped
-r--r--r-- root     root         4096 2012-03-15 17:03 multicast
-r--r--r-- root     root         4096 2012-03-15 17:03 collisions
-r--r--r-- root     root         4096 2012-03-15 17:03 rx_length_errors
-r--r--r-- root     root         4096 2012-03-15 17:03 rx_over_errors
-r--r--r-- root     root         4096 2012-03-15 17:03 rx_crc_errors
-r--r--r-- root     root         4096 2012-03-15 17:03 rx_frame_errors
-r--r--r-- root     root         4096 2012-03-15 17:03 rx_fifo_errors
-r--r--r-- root     root         4096 2012-03-15 17:03 rx_missed_errors
-r--r--r-- root     root         4096 2012-03-15 17:03 tx_aborted_errors
-r--r--r-- root     root         4096 2012-03-15 17:03 tx_carrier_errors
-r--r--r-- root     root         4096 2012-03-15 17:03 tx_fifo_errors
-r--r--r-- root     root         4096 2012-03-15 17:03 tx_heartbeat_errors
-r--r--r-- root     root         4096 2012-03-15 17:03 tx_window_errors
-r--r--r-- root     root         4096 2012-03-15 17:03 rx_compressed
-r--r--r-- root     root         4096 2012-03-15 17:03 tx_compressed
# cat /sys/devices/platform/smc91x.0/net/eth0/statistics/rx_bytes
410236
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need root to find it? (Not sure)
And make sure you're looking in the phone memory (not sdcard)